# Given a non-empty array of integers nums, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one

Tags: python, arrays

```
nums.sort()
i = 0
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
        i = i + 2
    else: 
        return nums[i]
```

Could someone please explain why this code doesn't work? The logic is whenever I find a duplicate, I will jump two numbers ahead and compare that number to the one after.

Thank you.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: For loops in python are not like for loops in C. You can't jump-ahead by increasing `i` like that. `i` will always take the next value from the `range()` iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use XOR operation for this problem, considering these properties:

- XOR of a number with itself is 0.
- XOR of a number with 0 is
  number itself.

```html
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        result = nums[0]
        for i in range(1,len(nums)):
            result = result ^ nums[i]
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit what a "for loop" is going to interate through during the "for loop" itself. For example, "for i in range(10)" means i will take on the values of 0,1,2,...,9. That cannot be changed. Even if I manipulate i in some way, like "i = i +7" or "i = str(i)" that does nothing to change what i will become during the start of each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying is possible with a for loop, because like what @rdas mentioned you can't jump ahead by increasing i like that. If you want to stick with your idea then you'd better use a **while loop** (something like the following, changes might be required),

```
nums.sort()
i = 0
while i <= len(nums)-1:
        if i == len(nums)-1:
                print(nums[i])
                break
        if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
                i += 2
        else:
                print(nums[i])
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Like previous answers have said, you can't change that i value within the for loop.

One option would be to use pythons built in count() function for lists:

```
for x in nums:
    if list(nums).count(x) == 1: 
        print(x)
```

An alternative solution would be to use the counter method in the collections package, iterate over your array items and and check whether the count is equal to one:

```
[x for x, count in collections.Counter(nums).items() if count == 1][0]
```